# adding jfxrt.jar to standard Eclipse build path

Tags: eclipse, build, path

How can I convince eclipse to include jfxrt.jar into its standard build path by default in order to avoid editing it manually every time I change the JVM?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The more convenient way is :

Go to > Window > Preferences > Installed JREs > Edit your jdk >1.7u7 location

Then click on "Add external Jar" and choose the jfxrt.jar provided by the Jdk.

All JavaFX classes will be available for all your projects , just by adding this custom Jdk

The pitfall is that you can't use *Execution Environment* because the jfxrt.jar has not been added into Eclipse jars definition of a Jdk.

Comment: "The pitfall is that you can't use Execution Environment because the jfxrt.jar has not been added into Eclipse jars definition of a Jdk." How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `jfxrt.jar` from  `Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jars`

Unfortunately, you need to do it for each project.

Comment: No, I don't need to do this. In Preference -> Installed JREs -> Edit I do add it to the JRE system libraries. - More precisely my question is how to add it permanently to the list proposed by eclipse.

Comment: but somewhere this list must be generated - who knows where?